# Issue with removing multiple rows at once from JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to make a button that, when multiple rows in a [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) are selected, all of the selected rows are removed.

I am creating an observable list using `getSelectedIndicies` and it isn't working right.

If I select the first three rows, I have it print out the indicies as it removes them and it prints 0,1 and then it removes the first and third row, but the middle of the three rows is not removed.

```
delBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        ObservableList<Integer> index = 
            table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();

        for (int location: index) {
            System.out.println(location);
            data.remove(location);
        }

        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is your for loop. You're removing by index. If you have items 1,2,3,4 and you remove index 0, you now have 2,3,4. Then you remove the item at index 1 (which is now 3), leaving you with 2,4.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for what I should do instead? I thought it might be something with the for loop, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, this works:

```
 b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    List items =  new ArrayList (treeTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());  
                    data.removeAll(items);
                    table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

                }
            });
```

I doubt that the internal implementation of the selectedItems list ( com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper ) might have some bug.

**Edit**
Yes it's definitely a bug: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24367

Comment: But sometimes you may have multiple Items of the same reference in the list, and you might only want to remove one of them, not two or more, so using this approach does not work in that case, since it will remove all such item references. For example, suppose your ListView<Fruit> contains {Apple, Banana, Banana, Orange}, and you only want to remove the first Banana, then using `removeAll` will remove all Bananas if they represent the same object, which you might want to do in some cases...

Answer (score 4):

Removing using index can't work since at each suppression the remaining indexes change.

You could remove the `selectedItems` :

```
delBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        data.removeAll(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, however when I do this regardless of what I have highlighted it clears the entire table. I tried using getSelectedIndicies() in there instead and it didn't remove anything.

Comment: Slight correction. It deletes everything below the highest highlighted  row. So if there are 100 rows and I highlight row 10-20 roes 10-99 are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop, it make a snapshoot of your table selection and iterate in it. For exmple:

```
@FXML
private void deleteButtonFired(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws InterruptedException {
    for(Object o : table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()){
        table.getItems().remove(o);
    }
    table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

I hope they fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue using ListView (selectedView in my case) and also guessed items were removed by indices. So I gave up on using a loop looking like the following

```
selectedView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(i -> selectedView.getItems().remove(i));
```

changing it to

```
selectedView.getItems().removeAll(selectedView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

which worked just fine. Hope this helps anybody.

Comment: @Wingle I've found the solution - see my answer :-D

Answer (score 0):

There is a way round this, using `getSelectedIndices()`, as the OP originally required. Here is the solution:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices());

    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue);
    comparator = comparator.reversed();
    list.sort(comparator);

    for(Integer i : list) {

        listView.getItems().remove(i.intValue());
    }
```

This works because it sorts the indices in descending order, and so only removes the highest index first so that the indices of other items to be removed are not changed as a result of the removal.

> Sometimes you can't use the `getSelectedItems()` and `removeAll(...)` functions because `removeAll` will remove all occurences of the referenced objects. What if your list contains multiple entries with the same referenced object, and you only want to remove one of those references? That's why you need to use the `getSelectedIndices()` function.