# Removing more than one row from TableView JavaFx

Tags: javafx, tableview, rows

I have similar problem for this --> [Issue with removing multiple rows at once from JavaFX TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700430/issue-with-removing-multiple-rows-at-once-from-javafx-tableview)

I am trying to make a button with will remove rows in a TableView using indexes.

When I execute this code remove only 0,2,4 indexes.

> b.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

```
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                data.remove(0);
                data.remove(1);
                data.remove(2);
                data.remove(3);
                data.remove(4);
            }
```

});

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove one entry at the beginning of the list, the items will move backwards. Moving the items backwards also changes their indexes. It's the reason why when you call data.remove(0), the previous data.get(1) will become data.get(0). What you can do then is something like:

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int numberOfItemsToRemove=4;
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfItemsToRemove;i++){
        data.remove(0);
    }
}
```

**Edit for your comment:**
Another solution would be to start removal from the highest index. Let's say you want to remove items with index 1, 6, and 9. You would then do something like:

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
    data.remove(9);
    data.remove(6);
    data.remove(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Of course it works when I want to remove indexes 1,2,3,4...
But when I want remove, for example, 1,6,9... it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

After you remove data(0), data(1) becomes data(0), data(2) becomes data(1) etc..
I see it has just been answered but I'll also mention,

For an ObservableList you have a remove(from, to) method so you could do `data.remove(0,4);`.

For a regular list you can remove a collection, so if you put all items to remove in a collection, then you do `data.removeAll(list);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I put all items to remove in a collection - It works the same way as before...

Comment: @dakar, sorry it's removeAll(list)

Answer (score 0):

try this...its worked..

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {


                data.remove(0);
                data.remove(1);
                data.remove(2);
               table.setItems(data);

        }
    });
```

Comment: @dakar but i am check it..it remove index no 0,2,4 row from table...can you find something else ???